# How to do a for loop in html(razor) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Hello guys i am trying to create a table with all information i have taken from an api in .cshtml.cs and to show them in the html page. But i can't quite figure it out.
This is code from .cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/xxx/api/v1/xxx");
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddHeader("AuthenticationToken", "xxx");
            request.AddHeader("Cookie", "_sid_=xx");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            RestResponse response = await client.GetAsync(request);
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            var resultArray = obj["result"].Values<JObject>();
          
            foreach (var item in resultArray)
            {
                get_article_id =item["articleId"].Value<int>();

                get_article_number =item["articleNumber"].Value<string>();
                
                get_quantity =item["quantity"].Value<int>();

                if(item["reservations"].Count() == 0)
                {
                    get_reserved_quantity = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    get_reserved_quantity = item["reservations"][0]["reservedQuantity"].Value<int>();       
                }

                get_name_item = await get_name_of_item(get_article_id);
            }
            return Page();
        }
        public int get_article_id { get; set; }
        public string get_article_number { get; set; }
        public int get_quantity { get; set; }
        public int get_reserved_quantity { get; set; }
        public string get_name_item { get; set; }
```

The code for .cshtml is:

```
<p>
    @Model.get_article_id
    @Model.get_article_number
    @Model.get_quantity
    @Model.get_reserved_quantity
    @Model.get_name_item
</p>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your properties hold just a single value each, which you keep overwriting in that loop - so you see just the last value.

Comment: OT the usual naming of a property is not `get_article_number` but `ArticleNumber` (no "get" and capitals instead of `_` to separate the parts)

Answer (score 3):

We can try to use create a class ViewModel to carry your data from API in C#

```
public class ViewModel{
    public int get_article_id { get; set; }
    public string get_article_number { get; set; }
    public int get_quantity { get; set; }
    public int get_reserved_quantity { get; set; }
    public string get_name_item { get; set; }
}
```

Then write a property `ViewModelList` in c#, we can use lambda to carry data in that.

```
public List<ViewModel> ViewModelList { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/xxx/api/v1/xxx");
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddHeader("AuthenticationToken", "xxx");
    request.AddHeader("Cookie", "_sid_=xx");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    RestResponse response = await client.GetAsync(request);
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    var resultArray = obj["result"].Values<JObject>();

    ViewModelList = resultArray.Select(item => new ViewModel()
    {
        get_article_id = item["articleId"].Value<int>(),
        get_article_number = item["articleNumber"].Value<string>(),
        get_quantity = item["quantity"].Value<int>(),
        get_reserved_quantity = item["reservations"].Any() ? item["reservations"][0]["reservedQuantity"].Value<int>() : 0
    }).ToList();
    return Page();
}
```

Final we can use `@foreach` in razor page to iterator `ViewModelList`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ViewModelList)
{
    <p>
        @item.get_article_id
        @item.get_article_number
        @item.get_quantity
        @item.get_reserved_quantity
        @item.get_name_item
    </p>
   
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i get an error in .cshtml. The error is System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Hi @sudsycloud which part did you get the error from `.cshtml`? I only modify `Model.ViewModelList` passing this property to that please make sure it fill data in c# as my sample code `ViewModelList`

Comment: I got the error in the first line of foreach in .cshtml  : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

FirstWebsite.Pages.IndexModel.ViewModelList.get returned null. And i have read your code and paste it to my code

Comment: @sudsycloud Could you try to use `public List<ViewModel> ViewModelList { get; set; } = new List<ViewModel>();` to instead `public List<ViewModel> ViewModelList { get; set; }`

Comment: sorry again but this time it worked but the data is not shown in page

Comment: @sudsycloud Could you debug your code call the API whether success & Did you add `@page` in cshtml https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244332/discussion-between-sudsycloud-and-d-shih).

Comment: With `var ViewModelList = ...` you are creating a new variable, not assigning to the property. Remove the `var`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Oops I didn't see that mistake thank you for your reminder

Comment: @sudsycloud I had edited my answer I think the problem is on HansKeﬆing's mentation.